# Typescript `Parameters<Fnc>` second argument unexpectedly returns `never`

Tags: typescript

I've got a function `trackEvent` that is typed correctly, but when using the Parameters utility, the type doesn't carry over in the same way.

Is there a way of using generics to correctly these arguments in an array format? (in the example `alternativeTrackEvent`)

The idea would be to pass it through a React component like this

```ts
<Button eventParams={['car', 'drive', { city: 'london'}]} />
```

```ts
export type Events = {
  car: {
    drive: { city: string };
  },
  plane: {
    fly: { country: string };
  }
};

export type TrackEvent = <K extends keyof Events, E extends keyof Events[K], P extends Events[K][E]>(
  tag: K,
  name: E,
  opts: P,
) => void;

const trackEvent: TrackEvent = (tag, name, opts) => console.log(tag, name, opts)

trackEvent('car', 'drive', { city: 'london'}) // works

trackEvent('plane', 'drive', { country: 'uk'}) // fails correctly

const alternativeTrackEvent: Parameters<TrackEvent> = ['car', 'drive', { city: 'london'}] // second argument is never
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiA3YA7GBnOAXjgG8AoOOAYwEMoAuUiyuAEygEstGTqOlGeGJ2wBzOAF8A3MwkAaZmAA2NbMB7NKAMyWIe1CAFdcUPXCEjx02WWtlQkWAmSoAKlBpUA1phzxiADwA0nCgMDisBF7AiBBa6Fi4eHLooSDh2JFw0bHxvkkA2kEAuikACmkZWfn4RcUFaMUAfAAUzDA0ooxBCpTYNAC26ui9cBBg+IxlCgCURE1wGBAcrDJkVBDYQgge3jWM7p4+if5wLR2iKf1DKeP4c4QLG1sQSsAAdEoQouedV4PAW4TPAzMhkYRHGotADktCg0JS0PYXGACNIfAEcGhX0ym2hEjmAHpCXAAO7QLx4MEQvYnGHKVSoxHIrBo3gbYzCMzQwxefFEklaGgcJQEDZQKDAKgwXRg57bGhKcJQfowFGHWl+KZ0AHKvABDXHPwLYgFWF0NFIzislLs-jcnGsPESYpwYnmKWbVhwOiiQxDXBwDgENRYKBAA)

Comment: TS doesn't have non-function generic values or higher order generics, so there's no way for `Parameters<TrackEvent>` to do anything useful for you; it just substitutes the constraints for the generic type arguments before evaluating, which is [blah](https://tsplay.dev/w2pjjm).  I don't see a question in your post; if it's "why does this happen" then I can write up an answer fleshing out my explanation above.  If it's some other question, what is it?

Comment: @jcalz You are right that there wasn't a question in there. I've updated it now to show what I was working towards and why I thought `Parameters` might have been it

Comment: There is no way to do this with a generic function type; but given the example I'd be inclined to refactor so that you're using a union of allowable parameter lists, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NB40nW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah that's the refactor that I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really support higher order [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) of the sort that would be necessary to represent `Parameters<TrackEvent>` without losing information.  Perhaps if TypeScript directly supported [existentially quantified generic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), then `Parameters<TrackEvent>` would be something like

```
type TrackEventParams = Parameters<TrackEvent>;
// the following is not valid TS syntax, don't try to use it
/*  type TrackEventParams = 
      <∃K extends keyof Events, ∃E extends keyof Events[K], ∃P extends Events[K][E]>[
        tag: keyof Events, name: never, opts: never
      ]
*/
```

where the fictitious generic syntax `type X = <∃T> F<T>` means "a value is of type `X` if it is there *exists* some type `T` where the value is of type `F<T>`".  But such generics types are not part of TypeScript.

[The `Parameters<T>` utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and when it needs to match a generic function against something it will just specify the type arguments as their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

So given your constraints `K extends keyof Events, E extends keyof Events[K], P extends Events[K][E]`, `Parameters<TrackEvent>` will behave as is `TrackEvent` were defined like

```
type K = keyof Events; // "car" | "plane"
type E = keyof Events[K]; // never; it's keyof a union with no common keys
type P = Events[K][E]; // never
type TrackEvent = (tag: K, name: E, opts: P) => void;
// type TrackEvent = (tag: keyof Events, name: never, opts: never) => void
```

The reason why `E` is `never` is because `Events["car"]` and `Events["plane"]` share no common property names, and `keyof` on a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) returns only key names known to exist on all members of the union.

---

Often when someone needs existentially quantified generics there's no equivalent specific type in TypeScript to use instead.  You can think of an existential type as the *union* of the type for all possible instantiations of the generic (whereas TypeScript's generics, and those of most other languages, are the *intersection* of the type for all possible instantiations of the generic).  When the generics are constrained to a type with an unlimited number of members (like `string`), then, you could think of an existential type as an "infinite union", and TypeScript's unions are sadly only finite.

But in your case, you have `K extends keyof Events`, a type that has only two values, `"car"` and `"plane"`, in its domain.  And once you've chosen `K`, then `E` has only a finite number of values in its domain.  So whereas *in general* existential types would be infinite unions, your example *in particular* can be represented by a finite union, and finite unions do exist in TypeScript.

Let's programmatically generate this union via a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)), which is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which one immediately [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
type TrackEventParams = { [K in keyof Events]:
  { [E in keyof Events[K]]:
    [tag: K, name: E, opts: Events[K][E]]
  }[keyof Events[K]]
}[keyof Events];

/* type TrackEventParams = 
    [tag: "car", name: "drive", opts: { city: string; }] | 
    [tag: "plane", name: "fly", opts: { country: string; }] */
```

That's a specific type you can use instead of `Parameters<TrackEvent>`:

```
const alternativeTrackEvent: TrackEventParams =
  ['car', 'drive', { city: 'london' }]; // okay
```

In fact, depending on your use cases, you could even redefine `TrackEvent` in terms of `TrackEventParams`:

```
export type TrackEvent = (...[tag, name, opts]: TrackEventParams) => void;
const trackEvent: TrackEvent = (tag, name, opts) => console.log(tag, name, opts)

trackEvent('car', 'drive', { city: 'london' }) // works
trackEvent('plane', 'drive', { country: 'uk' }) // fails correctly
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiA3YA7GBnOAXjgG8AoOOAYwEMoAuUiyuAEygEstGTqOlGeGJ2wBzOAF8A3MwkAaZmAA2NbMB7NKAMyWIe1CAFdcUPXCEjx02WWtlsNALbA8YGlVQBNQ1QDWTSlBIWARkVAAVKHdfTBx4Qk04AB4AaThQGBxWAl9gRAgtdCxcPDl0dJBM7Gy4XPzC2JKAbRSAXTKABQqqmsb8FtamtFaAPgAKRMoYGlFGFIUWFgdnRjQFxbgIMHxGDvXKAEoiEbgMCA5WGWYkFDhI6L6OuicCYieo50yoPCT7vz6RjJKAB6YEIAAWqC0ECUSggAHcOGI4BwCNgIPAMDQlBc7gBlcyIXA0EBlVgQbAAcngwkQCAgcEMeFQ-GYwIAVFMwncov9ijB3i8iHBJiwkoBgIjSGSyOTyBSKcVKcHFaG6Mtqcoa-LwAzK4q60uqBD6OraQ1GTVFi2msw19QVJTKy3UcDUWCgZS2O1dwHdVrgrWY7OBZGu3LSxDq8pNUjgoLgACJaFAE3AAD6J5SqYAJsO3VWRzUO-ptWPxt3AKCx-iU2X2miM7AcClwREwcGuhlUCCORwtsBQLaVmAcFx51BdYgmgbmstgitQcd3AtwMY2uZOpwutabbZ4XZHQgnM4XIFxsE3CIrtczRhRrWKzcrH3uz17xgLw-H86sWyhy88g8-KCo4rykHALQotgdrRtqrT0MwvBDFBMEPs0bTwYkTTrnA8yuluqxvt605msMgaUBITT3sWpqtIGlHUSarRXByoS3H8MTAc8oHClhOFJnQCZPi6CbsFwOZEfu4FUPwZgWEioixhIrTpiKizYbemYqGoQn4c+CY6IgulelJvDdsYtKCMIClKSpwahkE0A0tyHF9MKYwAHReRpojCZJ8GAXycQgXgX6nD+MjdtgQgILynFxIwrn8u5Np+bu+BhVFeAwsAHlwqIN6+XpwCSQc-5xX0YyUsmlJlJSYlYLV0myYwlJwtUFKUpIRzxvC0C+HgZDCEBcRVVmahNfVnCNWUZlGCYZiUoYvhdRIPVgloNAcEoBDdlAUDAFQMC6KGWXwNiXwOCOWBJQlgXxbgIVEMwTTVXQk0NcATVmS1cBtRS5JUpIzHnpsvg0IgQA)

Comment: Fantastic explanation and great links to the TS repo, I'll read up on them for sure. Thanks 